# Why am I receiving Maximum update depth exceeded error when i'm not looping setState

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am trying to write a deck component storing the rank and suit of the deck in a state array. I'm getting `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded` in the shuffleDeck function. shuffleDeck just takes in the state array and shuffles it. I'm only calling setState once so why am I getting the update depth error?

```
class Board extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       deck: [],
    }
  }

  shuffleDeck() {
    const newDeck = Shuffle(this.state.deck);
    this.setState({
      deck: newDeck,
    })
  }

  renderDeck() {

    const ListSquares = ({deck}) => (
      <>
        {deck.map((card, index) => (
          <Square key={index} id={index} rank={card[0]} suit={card[1]}></Square>
        ))}
      </>
    );
    return (
      <>
        <ListSquares deck={this.state.deck} />
      </>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.ranks.forEach(r => {
          this.props.suits.forEach(s => {
            this.setState(state => {
              const deck = [...state.deck, [r, s] ]
              return {
                deck,
              }
            })
          })
        })}
      </>
    );
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="grid">
        {this.renderDeck()}
        {this.shuffleDeck()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `shuffleDeck` in the render, that function updates state which causes a re-render = infinite loop.

Comment: Also, why are you returning something from `componentDidMount`? And why are you writing JSX in `componentDidMount`? Only side effects should go in there, nothing should be returned and no JSX.